# how to correctly include a file in php for cronjobs and for normal execution

Tags: php, cron, require

So I have a script that updates all currency rates for my webshop.
I am trying to have it run using a cronjob but when it's executed through a cronjob I get this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(.../.../core/dbcon.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/domain.com/wholesale/system/labs/cur.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '.../.../core/dbcon.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/domain.com/wholesale/system/labs/cur.php on line 2
```

I've also tried using the full link to include it but that seems to not work when running it manually and will also not work in cronjobs.

In the php file itself this is what I use to include it:

```
require(".../.../core/dbcon.php");
```

And when I manually run it, it returns all the currencies right, and updates them in the database.

How would I correctly require the file so it can execute using a cronjob and manually as well.

Comment: What error are you getting? The path to the file you're trying to include isn't much help.  Also it shouldn't matter how you're running the script.  Manually and from cron should both be the same.

Comment: I've edited the question with some more information.

Comment: Did you try using `__DIR__` like `require(__DIR__ . "/../../core/dbcon.php");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `require("./../../core/dbcon.php");`
or use absolute paths.

**UPDATE**

Answer has been updated - see comments below for more info.

Comment: Like stated I've already tried to use absolute paths, and using ../../ instead of .../.../ gives me the exact same results.

Comment: @KristoferAronSverrisson is dbcon.php in /var/www/domain.com/wholesale/core ?

Comment: @KristoferAronSverrisson and have you tried it like this? `./../../core/dbcon.php` also I guess the file name is all in lowercase, including the file extension (that caused me troubles once).

Comment: Or if it won't help, what I'd suggest is to print the current working directory, as relative paths are relative to the CWD. More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: using the last comment you made I figured it out. I didn't know that you could include files like that. I gues you learn something new every day, eh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60152/discussion-between-kristofer-aron-sverrisson-and-alex).